Should women recite the daily Nasi
Are women included in the custom to recite the Daily Nasi for the first 13 days  of Nissan? Or no, since it is positive and time bound is it proper for them not to?

Not even all men do this. Nor could there be any prohibition in women reading verses. There seems to be two relevant questions here you are conflating: is whatever benefit that's achieved by reading these verses on these days available to women as well, and do any particular groups of women actually do this that it could serve as a binding custom on other women in the group?

https://asktherav.com/20224-nasi-for-women-and-for-geirim/
